# XSLT if >1 and if < 0

Tags: xslt, if-statement

If i write

```
<xsl:if test="$currentPage/seaside > 0">Seaside</xsl:if><br />
<xsl:if test="$currentPage/blueflag > 0">Blueflag</xsl:if><br />
<xsl:if test="$currentPage/family > 0">Family</xsl:if><br />
```

Seaside and Family have 1 so are shown in output. Blueflag has 0 so is not. 
My list has a space in the middle

```
'Seaside 

Family'
```

How do i remove the blank space and for nothing to be written if value is 0?

Comment: @IanRoberts: Even if it might not be the correct answer in this particular case, it may be for another visitor of this question, searching for "xsl" and "whitespace"... Of course, it might not be the accepted answer, then :-)

Comment: @LukasEder I think I see now, the OP's original question had `<br />` tags after each `</xsl:if>`, which were removed by a subsequent edit.

Comment: @IanRoberts: Aaah, nice catch! I thought that was an attempt to format the code here on Stack Overflow. But you may be right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `<br />` elements inside their respective `if` elements:

```
<xsl:if test="$currentPage/seaside > 0">Seaside<br /></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="$currentPage/blueflag > 0">Blueflag<br /></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="$currentPage/family > 0">Family<br /></xsl:if>
```

That way, the line break will only be produced in the case where the `test` is true.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it all on one line.

Comment: Not so. Unless perhaps the stylesheet says xsl:space="preserve".